# Nested SVG foreignObject font-size display error in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

I am trying to make custom CTA buttons that are created through SVG shapes - I tried with CSS, but this way(SVG) I am not falling into box-model issues of activating the button when hovering outside of the shape.

The problem is that text dipslayed through foreignObject nested in SVG elements:

```
<foreignObject x="5000" y="0" width="10000" height="17320.5">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <h2>M1</h2>
    </div>
  </foreignObject>
```

is being displayed differently in Chrome and Firefox. It is perfectly visible on Chrome, but Firefox scales it down and is not responding to further font-size change to bigger sizes.

[image presenting the issue](http://take.ms/ebTwP)

I created this [codepen](https://codepen.io/bkudyba/pen/rQzQOV) code snippet to demonstrate the problem.

I tried working around foreignObject with SVG text element, but I encountered another issue - Firefox ignores or miscalculates dimensions of the nested SVG elements.

Screens of different sizing of the same SVG nested element - [Chrome](http://take.ms/0CRwG), [Firefox](http://take.ms/8LmS5)

Have anyone faced such problem? I need to present consistent font-size on these buttons on both browsers (scaled font on FF is barely visible) and I want to avoid absolute positioning html span elements over these SVG buttons - this would present 2 separate buttons, one of text and one of an image to users and web crawlers.

Comment: May I ask why do you need to use `<foreignObject>` instead of using the `<text>` tag?

Comment: @enxaneta I am currently trying to use text tag, but I have problem with centering it so that no matter what text will be placed in it, it will automatically place it in center of the button

I mentioned this issue above - in my case Firefox calculates the x, y, width and height positions of nested svgs incorrectly. I tried to use x="50%" y="50%" and then translate the text tag by -50% on x and y axis, but due to these miscalculations (I think it is the problem) it does not place them in the center of the button.

If you have any tips on how to use the text tag I am willing to switch to it

Comment: @enxaneta preferably I wanted to use h2 tag due to SEO purposes

Comment: You can center text in SVG. Supposing you have a point x="120" y="60" you can center your text using like this: `<text  dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle"  x="120" y="60">`

Comment: If accessibility is in your mind please google "SVG ARIA attributes"

Comment: I tried a simplified version (cutting out the attributes and most of the styles) and it worked. You should be able to create a [mcve] here. And then determine what is it fixes the font-size in your case.

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you for the idea, it works like charm. I need to explore ARIA attributes.

Additionally I had some troubles with x axis misplacement, but that was due to my wrong understanding of text-anchor middle. For anyone having the issue the x coordinate in this case is the coordinate of middle point of the text element - [MDN - text-anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor).